# How can I make this Stack struct define?

Tags: swift, struct, stack

I want to make this Stack struct properly.

How can I define '`topItem`'?

Is it right to show above "`newstack`"?

```
    struct Stack {
    var Items:[String] = []



    mutating func push (item:String){
        Items += [item]
    }

    mutating func pop() -> String {
        return Items.removeLast()
    }

    var topItem =`enter code here`

    }

var newStack = Stack()

newStack.push("HistoryListController")
newStack.push("HistoryDetailViewController")
newStack.push("HistoryTimelineViewController")
newStack.push("HistoryChartViewController")

newStack.Items


if let topVC = newStack.topItem {
    print("Top View Controller is \(topVC)")
    //HistoryChartViewController
}

newStack.pop()

if let topVC = newStack.topItem {
    print("Top View Controller is \(topVC)")
    //HistoryTimelineViewController
}
```

I'm very beginner in Swift.
This is my first code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `items` should be lowercase. Second, it's not clear what you want `topItem` to return. If you want the most recent object, you could implement it like this:

```
struct Stack {
    var items = [String]()

    mutating func push (item:String){
        items += [item]
    }

    mutating func pop() -> String {
        let result = items[0]
        items.removeLast()
        return result
    }

    var topItem : String? {
        return items.last
    }

}

var newStack = Stack()

newStack.push("HistoryListController")
newStack.push("HistoryDetailViewController")
newStack.push("HistoryTimelineViewController")
newStack.push("HistoryChartViewController")

newStack.topItem // "HistoryChartViewController"

newStack.items
```

If you want the first object, change it to `return items.first`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure `pop()` does what I'd expect - it returns the first object always, and removes the last. Typically a `pop()` method would return the last object, and remove it.

Comment: and I changed

   [ let result = items[0]
    items.removeLast()
    return result  ]

to return [ items.removeLast()  ]

Comment: @SnowcatJung Seems like you could just use an array of strings, you don't really need your own `Stack` struct